# Distribution of quadratic residues in an interval

Tags: nt.number-theory, quadratic-residues

For a prime (or prime power) $p$ and some absolute constant $C$ (say $C$ = 100), consider the set $A$ of all $1 \leq a \leq p/C$ such that $1 \leq a^2 \leq p/C$ modulo $p$. Is it known that $|A| = \Omega(p)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. The points $(\frac{a}p,\frac{a^2\pmod p}p)$ are asymptotically equidistributed in $[0,1]^2$ by Weyl's criterion.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please give a reference to this result?

Comment: Read about Weyl's criterion here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence

Comment: And why is it applicable here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum

Comment: Of course one needs a multidimensional Weyl criterion here, see e.g. Prop. 1 at https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/254b-notes-1-equidistribution-of-polynomial-sequences-in-torii/